# Requests/min and Android Development

Tags: parse-platform

Currently my app easily reaches 2-5 requests/min with 5 users.  From my understanding of Parse this is rather high.

To give an example of what we do is:
  When a user logs on and refreshes the list is filled with all relevant information from the database (query that specific user and gather all of his event/group data from server)

When a user creates an event, create all of the data and pass it to the server.

From my understanding a request/min is only when you make a network call.  In this case, I see that when a user refreshes that is 1 network call as well as when a user creates an event it is 1 network call.  Is there something I am missreading about request calls?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your understanding is wrong. 2 - 5 requests per minute is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 requests per second is the (current) baseline limit (1800 per minute).

1 network request could be multiple requests for a number of reasons (batch processing, calling a cloud function, anything which has a save hook, ...). Depending on the API you use you could be requesting a batched save of multiple objects for instance.

If all of your users are continually averaging 1 request per second then you have a problem. If your users each have a short burst of 5 per second followed by a long period of no requests then you're fine.